# jQuery: Slide left and slide right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen `slideUp` and `slideDown` in jQuery. What about functions/ways for sliding to left and right?

Comment: You can simply do an `animate({width: 0})` then set position right or left for it to look like sliding right or left.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do this with the additional effects in jQuery UI: [See here for details](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide)

Quick example:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Comment: This seems to be dependent on **Effects Core**, isn't there way to achieve this without any external stuff?

Comment: @Sarfraz - Not that I know of, then you're reinventing the wheel anyway...one note that may be helpful, keep the direction the same for hide/show, it's the direction it comes from or goes to...it's somewhat counter-intuitive that it's the same, but you get used to it.

Comment: @Sarfraz - You can try and pull the pieces you need if you want, lots of effort though, start here if you're going down that route: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/branches/dev/effects/ui/effects.slide.js?r=2454

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want something bloated like [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI), try my custom animations: https://github.com/yckart/jquery-custom-animations

For you, `blindLeftToggle` and `blindRightToggle` is the appropriate choice.

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/65QsU/

Comment: Thanks for these awesome functions.. I was looking for easy things like this forever. And it works like a charm.

Comment: when i want to do that the console says me
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blindLeftToggle' `

Answer (score 6):

You can always just use jQuery to add a class, `.addClass` or `.toggleClass`. Then you can keep all your styles in your CSS and out of your scripts.

http://jsfiddle.net/B8L3x/1/

Answer (score 0):

This code works well :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var options = {};
            $("#c").hide();
            $("#d").hide();
            $("#a").click(function(){
                 $("#c").toggle( "slide", options, 500 );
                 $("#d").hide();
            });
            $("#b").click(function(){
                 $("#d").toggle( "slide", options, 500 );
                 $("#c").hide();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            nav{
            float:left;
            max-width:300px;
            width:300px;
            margin-top:100px;
            }
            article{
            margin-top:100px; 
            height:100px;
            }
            #c,#d{
            padding:10px;
            border:1px solid olive;
            margin-left:100px;
            margin-top:100px;
            background-color:blue;
            }
            button{
            border:2px solid blue;
            background-color:white;
            color:black;
            padding:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <center>hi</center>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <button id="a">Register 1</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button id="b">Register 2</button>
         </nav>

        <article id="c">
            <form>
                <label>User name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="123" value="something"/>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="text" name="456" value="something"/>
            </form>
        </article>
        <article id="d">
            <p>Hi</p>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Reference:W3schools.com and jqueryui.com

Note:This is a example code 
don't forget to add all the script tags in order to achieve proper functioning of the code.