# slide left or right and slide from top-left corner and more

Tags: jquery

> There is slideUp(), slideDown() and slideToggle() function in jQuery. But why not slideLeft(), slideRight(), slideTopLeftCorner(), slideTopRightCorner() and so on functions are added? Is there anyway to do like my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can use so:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

[Here is duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411314/jquery-slide-left-and-slide-right)

And [here is through plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show)

From right bottom to left top corner try so.
In another way - you can change options marginLeft and marginTop in function.

```
jQuery.fn.blindLeftTopOut = function (duration, easing, complete) {
    return this.animate({
        marginLeft: -this.outerWidth(),
        marginTop:  -this.outerHeight()
    }, jQuery.speed(duration, easing, complete));
};
$(element).blindLeftTopOut();
```

Comment: and what about slideTopRightCorner()

Comment: @c-link depending on your CSS, but usually achieved by default with `.hide(800)`