# Sliding a div from right to left via jQuery or CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jsfiddle. I'm trying to get the right hand side div to slide to where the left div is when a user clicks on any of the example links, i can't figure out how to do this as im fairly new to CSS3 transitions and jquery. Could someone help guide me in the right direction. I've had a look at jQuery animate too but find it a little confusing.

The transition should work in IE10+, anything below it's fine if it doesnt have a transition

http://jsfiddle.net/AV22p/

Below is the structure of my HTML

```
<section id="modalwindow">
    <div id="foodlist">
        <div class="links">
            <h1>Div 1</h1>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Example1    </li></a>
                    <li><a href="#">Example2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example8</a></li>
                </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="modalwindow">
    <div id="food_details">
        <div class="details">
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>test </li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
           </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411314/jquery-slide-left-and-slide-right?rq=1?

Comment: I don't see any CSS or JavaScript attempts in your code to perform a slide.

Comment: id's must be unique within a web page and you're using modalwindow twice. You have some other problems in your markup. Other than that, have you tried any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want since the description is quite vague. But you might be able to convert this to your needs.

`divWidth` checks for the with of the section. On click of a link the section containing `#food_details` gets moved the (negative)width of `#modalwindow` to the LEFT.

```
$('.links ul li a').click(function(){
    var divWidth = '-'+$('#modalwindow').width();
    $('#food_details').parent().animate({left: divWidth});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AV22p/3/

Also note that your first example link has a different/invalid markup than the rest.