# How do I show/hide a div with a slide effect? Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm completely new to jQuery and I'm trying to create my own  navigation bar which slides in from the right on click.

I found a snippet online which shows and hides my div with slideToggle but rather than it just appear I'd like it to smoothly slide in from the right. 
Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".menu").hide();
  $("#drop-icon").show();

  $('#drop-icon').click(function(){
  $(".menu").slideToggle(1000);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: jQuery doesn't really have anything built in, other than `animate`, but jQuery UI does have a built in slide-right -> https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: Slide left and slide right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411314/jquery-slide-left-and-slide-right)

Answer (score 0):

Hello try the below code hope you are looking for this . . . i did it with less code but effective .Hope it helps.

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
 $('.inner').toggleClass('visible');
 $('.inner').animate({
  width: 'toggle',
 
 },500);
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 5px 0px;
 position: absolute;  
}

#menu  ul li{
    display: inline;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
 width:100px;
 
}

.inner {
    float: right;
     display: none;
 padding-right: 5px;
 background-color:pink;

}

#button1 {    
    margin-right: 5px;
 justify:center:
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;">
 <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-success">Menu</button>
    </div>
 <div class='toolbar'>
    <div class="inner is-hidden">
        <div id="menu">  
    <ul >
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```